# Where is the source code for isnan?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, double

Because of the layers of standards, the include files for c++ are a rats nest.  I was trying to figure out what `__isnan` actually calls, and couldn't find anywhere with an actual definition.

So I just compiled with -S to see the assembly, and if I write:

```
#include <ieee754.h>

void f(double x) {
  if (__isinf(x) ...

  if (__isnan(x)) ...
}
```

Both of these routines are called.  I would like to see the actual definition, and possibly refactor things like this to be inline, since it should be just a bit comparison, albeit one that is hard to achieve when the value is in a floating point register.

Anyway, whether or not it's a good idea, the question stands: WHERE is the source code for `__isnan(x)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glibc has versions of the code in the [sysdeps](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/tree/HEAD:/sysdeps) folder for each of the systems it supports. The one you’re looking for is in [sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_isnan.c](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_isnan.c). I found this with `git grep __isnan`.

(While C++ headers include code for templates, functions from the C library will not, and you have to look inside glibc or whichever.)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_isnan.c;h=3a089e99a853d380c954eac724835de6a74adafd;hb=master), for the master head of glibc, for instance.