# Is it possible to generate random floating point numbers including subnormals, with rand() of math.h?

Tags: c, random, c99

I would like to generate floating point numbers that include subnormal floating point numbers. Can we use the routine `rand()` of `math.h` to achieve this The programming language should be `C99`. I want this random number to be uniformly distributed from [-1e308 to 1e308].

Comment: Note that using `rand` this will always be pseudo-random number, not a true random.

Comment: Generate the sign, fraction and the exponent part using `rand`, and recompose them to `float`.

Comment: See [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/SVID-Random.html#SVID-Random)

Comment: @RossPresser What part of glibc?

Comment: @RossPresser You won't get denormals with that.

Comment: @this I think you do as the documentation says “uniformly distributed.” Denormal must have a positive probability of appearing.

Comment: @FUZxxl Are you sure about that? Do you exactly mean that subnormals can be generated by rand() of math.h?

Comment: @FUZxxl You are misusing uniform distribution in this context.

Comment: @this the glibc manpage says that `drand48` generates uniformly distributed numbers in the range [0, 1.0). How am I misusing this word?

Comment: @FUZxxl Becase uniform distribution doesn't mean every possible value will be generated, when dealing with floating point.

Comment: @zell Generate a random floating point value between 0 and 1, and then divide by a large power of 2 to get denormals.

Comment: Please specify a distribution and a range, otherwise this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Let's also think pragmatically about this.  Assuming you mean uniform in [0,1), you would only expect to see a denormal once every 1E21 years (approximately) even if you were generating 1 billion randoms per second.  Are you sure you want this?

Comment: @this I do not thing one can get subnormal using your approach. One would get 0.

Comment: @zell: If you want uniformly-distributed, why have you accepted an answer that very definitely does not give you a uniform distribution?

Comment: @zell Certainly you want an approximate  _logarithmic_ distribution from [-1e308 to 1e308] and not uniform linear one.  IOWs there are about as many random numbers generated between 1.0 to 2.0 as there are between 1e6 to 2e6 and well as 1e-6 to 2e-6.

Comment: @zell No, you would get a denormal if you pick the power correctly.

Comment: @this. Would you give more details, if you can, maybe as an answer to the question? Sorry but I do not see a viable way you can get subnormals with your claimed apporach.

Comment: @zell Divide a float by a larger float, until you get a denormal. Use a while loop, division operator and printf to see the value of the float..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
union {
  int a;
  float b;
} Number;

Number.a = rand();
printf("%f\n", Number.b);
```

this uses the bitmask of a random integer to create a float number with the same bitmask.

Comment: It seems a reasonable answer. Someone downvoted however. Why?

Comment: This approach is unportable. Writing to one union member and then reading from another is unspecified behaviour.

Comment: @Bathsheba can you explain why? it is correct in c99 if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`. It is okay to write to one member of an union and read from another if they occupy the same bytes since c99.

Comment: @mch Because a member can have a trap representation.

Comment: What is the distribution of the random numbers generated with this approach?

Comment: Note: as `rand()` generates the value `0...RAND_MAX` which does not include negative `int`, likely half of the possible `float` will not be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to one field of a union and reading from another often has troubles, but the following works well-enough on many systems:

This will generate not-a-numbers.  [NAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

```
double random_double(void) {
  union {
    unsigned char uc[sizeof (double)];
    double d;
  } u;
  unsigned i;
  for (i=0; i<sizeof u.uc; i++) {
    u.uc[i] = rand();
  }
  return u.d;
}
```

A way to not return NAN.  Also see [IEEE 754 specifies an isNaN() predicate which does not raise an exception even when used with signaling NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8181742/2410359)

```
double rand_double_NotNAN(void) {
  union {
    double d;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof(double)];
  } u;
  do {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++) {
      u.uc[i] = rand();
    }
  } while (isnan(u.d));
  return u.d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't be efficient, but to properly answer the question:

first define a mapping from the integer range (0, MAX_RAND) to the reals. In defining this mapping, decide exactly what distribution you want: uniform over all reals, or logarithmically uniform, or whatever. Write a function that given an integer in the range, returns a double according to this mapping. Now use rand() and feed it into your function.